# UTF-8 conversion is not happening for larger size

Tags: android, utf-8, character-encoding, android-volley, utf-16

I am unable to understand why utf-8 conversion is not happening for the data which is near to 1 MB, network data which I am getting it has some special characters and they are not properly rendered in the app, below line converts data successfully for smaller size but not data which is of size near to 1mb

`responseString = new String(response.toString().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");`

I want to understand whether utf-8 format conversion has the size limit in java?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not convert from *ISO-8859-1* to *UTF-8*, it converts your `response.getString()` string (from *UTF-16* internal `String` representation) to *ISO-8859-1* and interpret it as *UTF-8*. It is incorrect, and won't work for bytes >= 128 (negatives bytes in Java).

If you want the *UTF-8* representation of your response string:

```
byte[] utf8Response = response.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Didn't work..!, what i am trying here is to overcome from junk character to valid character. same character are converting and showing properly in other with screen with code shown above, the same methodology didn't working in other screen